# Problems with updating Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget-package

After New Years are over I'm at the office again and started to update the packages of my Xamarin project, that I wrote over the last two months.

I got the error:

```
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

What do I have to do, to handle the error?

Comment: `Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0` package doesn't seem to have a folder for `.NETFramework, Version=v4.6.2` hence the project is unable to find the right .dll you should contact the Microsoft team for the same.

Comment: @G.hakim : Given your suggestion to contact the Microsoft team, I create an [issue on their tracker](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2575).

Comment: Great keep me updated as to what was the solution here. Thanks